# docker-compose bind local folder into a container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Until now, I was mounting my local directory through the `docker run` command line. My local folder was correctly mounted into my docker container, so I could modify my app freely and let my docker container live-reload my changes.

```
docker run --name myApp -t -a STDOUT -v E:/Projects/myApp/sveltekit:/app/sveltekit myappimage:latest
```

But now, i'm trying to achieve the same thing in a docker-compose.yml file, and it doesn't seems to work at all.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes: 
      - ./sveltekit/:/app/sveltekit
  
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: app
    volumes:
    - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

for this part :

```yaml
volumes: 
      - ./sveltekit/:/app/sveltekit
```

I tried everything. Absolute path, path starting with '/', './' but nothing seems to work properly, my sveltekit folder don't want to mount into my container. Do you know why nothing is working ?

Comment: try: `- ./sveltekit:/app/sveltekit`